# How can i disable Windows Automatic Update in Google Cloud

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-update

I have setup several Windows Server 2102 R2 instances in Google Cloud and need top be able to control the windows update settings, but they are currently listed as "Managed by your system administrator"

I have tried to disable this by setting the **disable-agent-updates** value to true in project metadata but this has not worked.

Does anyone know of another way to do this maybe what i might be doing wrong?

Many Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

When updates are "Managed by your system administrator" this implies that the servers are being configured for updates by group policy or a local WSUS server or Google cloud services. 
Things to check, if the servers are domain joined look at the group policy settings with `GPRESULT /R`

See This answer relating to how to check for WSUS servers
https://superuser.com/questions/189704/how-can-i-check-if-a-computer-is-configured-to-use-wsus

And on Google cloud instances try the following:

> On the Windows Server instance, open a PowerShell terminal as an
>   administrator. Run the googet remove command to remove the package:
>
> PS C:> googet remove google-compute-engine-auto-updater Optionally,
>   you can reinstall the package to enable automatic component updates:
>
> On the Windows Server instance, open a PowerShell terminal as an
>   administrator. Run the googet install command to install the package:
>
> PS C:> googet install google-compute-engine-auto-updater
>   Alternatively, you can disable the updates by setting the
>   disable-agent-updates value to true in project or instance custom
>   metadata. The metadata value disables updates without removing the
>   package or the task.

Comment: I was concerned about using the googet command as i only want to disable windows updates not all google updates.  I have already tried the last option "you can disable the updates by setting the disable-agent-updates value to true in project or instance custom metadata. The metadata value disables updates without removing the package or the task."

Comment: anything you set in metadata usually on executes on boot (from my experience with other clouds) so this may not take effect until you reboot. if google cloud uses cloud-init that you should be able to consult those logs within the configuration drive

Comment: A point of clarification: WSUS doesn't manage nor control the Windows Updates settings on client machines.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found (detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-managing-windows-instances#disable-component-update)) is to update the metadata for the VM:
And add the `disable-agent-updates`and `true`.